# pandas - self-join with date comparison

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge, self-join

Given a Pandas dataframe `df`

```
     date         numeric_field
0   2019-06-06       n
1   2019-06-07       n
2   2019-06-08       n
```

I would like to do a self-join on the dates and apply a function to the `numerical_field`.

In SQL I would have done something like:

```
SELECT a.date,
        FUN(b.numeric_field))) new_field
        FROM df a
        INNER JOIN df b
        ON b.date < a.date 
        WHERE a.date > '2019-06-06'
        AND a.date <= '2019-06-08'
        AND b.date >= '2019-06-06'
        GROUP BY a.date
```

the result should be:

```
     date           new_field
0   2019-06-07       fun(n)
1   2019-06-08       fun(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way I can think of is a cross merge and query:

```
df = df.assign(dummy=1)

(df.merge(df, on='dummy', suffixes=['','_r'])
   .query('"2019-06-06"<=date_r<date<="2019-06-08"')       # filter
   .assign(new_field=lambda x: x['numeric_field'].sum())   # replace the function in `lambda`
   [['date','new_field']]
)
```

Output:

```
         date new_field
3  2019-06-07       nnn
6  2019-06-08       nnn
7  2019-06-08       nnn
```

Comment: instead of `x['numeric_field']` should be `x['numeric_field_r']`